# What does refresh_pattern -i regex Min percentage Max mean?

Tags: server, cache, squid

I have configured squid cache proxy server on ubuntu server 16.04 it is working well I could understand all the things I have done except above line of code can anyone briefly tell me what does it mean specially (Min % Max) part and what does percentage do here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are THREE options you need to change. From the [configuration](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/refresh_pattern/):

- 'Min' is the time (in minutes) an object without an explicit
  expiry time should be considered fresh. The recommended
  value is 0, any higher values may cause dynamic applications
  to be erroneously cached unless the application designer
  has taken the appropriate actions.
- 'Percent' is a percentage of the objects age (time since last
  modification age) an object without explicit expiry time
  will be considered fresh.
- 'Max' is an upper limit on how long objects without an explicit
  expiry time will be considered fresh.